# How to blur a table cell within content editable

Tags: javascript, jquery, focus, contenteditable, blur

I have a simple table within a content editable div like so:

```
<div contenteditable="true">
    <table class="rwd-table" width="100%">
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

When you click a cell, I'm using jQuery to add an ID to that cell. The ID has CSS applied to highlight it.

```
$(document).on('click', 'td, th', function (event) {
    // remove previous highlighted cell
    $('#selectedCell').removeAttr('id');
    // highlight new cell
    $(this).attr('id', 'selectedCell');
});
```

When the highlighted cell looses focus, the ID should be removed. This is my problem.

```
// DOES NOT WORK  :(   //
$(document).on('blur', '#selectedCell', function (event) {
    $('#selectedCell').removeAttr('id');
});
```

I'm assuming it's because table cells don't normally have focus/blur events.

**Is there a way to detect blur on a table cell within contenteditable?**

Here is a live example: http://jsfiddle.net/5c7br6zc/

Comment: Tnkz very much my friend! =D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the problem with blur event. Instead of relying on it try to bind click event on `document` and prevent it from bubbling in case if click occurred on TD:

```
$(document).on('click', 'td, th', function (event) {
    $('#selectedCell').removeAttr('id');
    $(this).attr('id', 'selectedCell');
    event.stopPropagation();
});

$(document).on('click', function (event) {
    $('#selectedCell').removeAttr('id');
});
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/5c7br6zc/1/

Comment: Will not work when tabbing out of the cell. I'll add a solution when I find one